# String translation function for pgSQL

Tags: postgresql

Can someone provide an example of pgSQL function for translation of input string just substituting chars according to the template strings?

Comment: You mean the `translate()` function? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

Comment: Yes, That's exactly what I am looking for